# How to wrap legend items in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, legend

I have a big problem using highcharts, because I have been trying for hours  to wrap legend items if they very long.

I have tried to set legend and legend item width, but my text still get out from a legend. Only thing that I found is to change `highcharts.src.js` but I think that's not a way to solve this problem.

Here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'graph_container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
        zoomType: 'y',
        marginRight: 130,
        marginBottom: $ {
          marginBottom
        }
      },
      title: {
        x: -10,
        text: null
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: '<fmt:message key="html.time" bundle="${msg}"/>',
          align: 'high'
        },
        categories: [$ {
          years
        }]
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: '<fmt:message key="html.value" bundle="${msg}"/>',
          align: 'high'
        },
        plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          width: 1,
          color: '#808080'
        }]
      },
      tooltip: {
        style: {
          fontSize: '9pt',
          width: '400px', //,
          wrap: 'hard'
        },
        formatter: function() {
          return '<b>' + this.series.name + '<br>' +
            +this.x + ': ' + this.y + '</b>';
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        width: 600,
        floating: true,
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        borderWidth: 1,
        itemWidth: '500px'

      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [ <
        c: forEach items = "${graphValues}"
        var = "value"
        varStatus = "counter" >
        <
        c: if test = "${counter.count != 1}" > , < /c:if> {
          name: '${value.name}',
          data: $ {
            value.jsonData
          }
        } <
        /c:forEach>
      ]
    });


  });
</script>
```

Comment: > Only thing that I found is to change highcharts.src.js but I think that's not a way to solve this problem. Please, tell me what you changed in the source code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: Actually setting the item width did work, probably a better solution.

<strike>Setting the itemWidth doesn't work for me</strike>, however you can do something like this:

```
labelFormatter: function() {
    var words = this.name.split(/[\s]+/);
    var numWordsPerLine = 4;
    var str = [];

    for (var word in words) {
        if (word > 0 && word % numWordsPerLine == 0)
            str.push('<br>');

        str.push(words[word]);
    }

    return str.join(' ');
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ArmRM/13520/ for an example.

Comment: Just wanted to provide working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ArmRM/15041/. The old one is not working for me because of 404 for an external script.

Comment: <br/> within label text breaks the export to image. I get the first line exported. legend itemStyle width is no help for me as I am using 45degree labels and width only seems to apply to horizontal width.

Answer (score 42):

You can use:

```
legend: {
    itemStyle: {
        width: 90 // or whatever
    },
}
```

And Highcharts will wrap the items for you.

Comment: I've got a problem with itemStyle... it breaks my labelFormatter! I don't know why, but if I add a <strong> tag to the returned string it works well until the carriage return, after that the string is displayed with no bold...

Comment: @Janky I have this problem too, with line breaks breaking styles. Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: @supertrue yes, look here http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=20140&p=80261#p80261

Answer (score 9):

as a note, in 2017 you can use `textOverflow` option

> `legend.itemStyle`
>
> CSS styles for each legend item. Only a subset of CSS is supported,
>   notably those options related to text. **The default `textOverflow`
>   property makes long texts truncate. Set it to `null` to wrap text
>   instead.**

Answer (score 3):

Way to wrap long legend name

```
legend: {
    enabled: true,
    width:555,
    itemWidth:500,
    itemStyle: {
        width:500
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the itemStyle on the legend has a bug.  Long labels with no spaces still don't wrap.

[image]

Here is a label renderer function that wraps to a specific number of characters (I hard coded 20 into it) and will force a break in words that are longer than that:

```
function hcLabelRender(){
    var s = this.name;
    var r = "";
    var lastAppended = 0;
    var lastSpace = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') lastSpace = i;
        if (i - lastAppended > 20) {
            if (lastSpace == -1) lastSpace = i;
            r += s.substring(lastAppended, lastSpace);
            lastAppended = lastSpace;
            lastSpace = -1;
            r += "<br>";
        }
    }
    r += s.substring(lastAppended, s.length);
    return r;
}
```

[image]

It can be used like:

```
legend:{
    labelFormatter: hcLabelRender
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all items on their own lines, you can use

```
legend: {
    layout: "vertical"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
labelFormatter: function() {
    return this.name; // insert your formatter function here
}
```

in your label and you can add html tags in the formatter. In this case you can add `<br>` tags to manually break lines.

Please see:
http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#legend--labelFormatter

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else using the `useHTML` option, you'll run into an issue with the default `textOverflow: "ellipsis"` setting messing with your wrapping.

As teran noted above, setting `textOverflow: null` inside `itemStyle` will instantly fix your wrapping when `useHTML` is enabled and you're trying to wrap custom HTML you've written inside `legendFormatter()`.

Without this, the default truncation doesn't apply to your HTML (e.g. not a string) and just acts like you have `overflow: hidden` set.